# Show that edge paths in a simplicial complex are equivalent if they're homotopic relative to their endpoints in the simplicial complex's realisation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, path-connected, simplicial-complex

> Let K be a simplicial complex, and let $α_1$ and $α_2$ be edge paths. Suppose that $α_1$ and $α_2$ are homotopic relative to their endpoints. Show that $α_1$ and $α_2$ are equivalent as edge paths.

(where we've defined paths to be equivalent if they can be obtained from one another by a finite sequence of the following moves or their reverse, where the $a_i$ in the descriptions of the rules are the sequence of vertices the edge path follows:

$(0)$ replacing $. . . , a_{i−1}, a_i
, . . .$ by $. . . , a_{i−1}, . . .$ provided $a_{i−1} = a_i$
;

$(1)$ replacing $. . . , a_{i−1}, a_i
, a_{i+1}, . . . $ by $. . . , a_{i−1}, . . . ,$ provided $a_{i−1} = a_{i+1}$;

(2) replacing $. . . , a_{i−1}, a_i
, a_{i+1}, . . .$ by $. . . , a_{i−1}, a_{i+1}, . . .,$ provided {$a_{i−1}, a_i
, a_{i+1}$} span a 2-simplex of $K$.

[Here's a diagram showing what (1) and (2) look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUqfA.png))

I've shown in a similar question that the group of equivalence classes edge *loops* based at a point is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the realisation $|K|$ of $K$ based at a point, which shows that any homotopic edge loops are equivalent, but I don't know how to modify the approach in this case, since the equivalence classes of edge *paths* don't form a group in the same way so I can't employ the same strategy.

UPDATE: I've put a bit more thought into it, and here's where I'm at:

If I let $I_{(n)}$ be the triangulation of $I=[0, 1]$ with $n$ 1-simplices, each of length $1/n$, then I can regard an edge path of length $n$ as a simplicial map $I_{(n)}\rightarrow K$, which defines a mapping

$f:$ {equivalence classes of edge paths in $K$ with endpoints $x, y$} $\rightarrow $ {homotopy classes of paths in $|K|$ with endpoints $x, y$}.

If I can show that $f$ is injective - that if $f([α_1])=f([α_2])$ then $[α_1]=[α_2]$ then I'm done.

The trouble is there's no identity because I'm not mapping into a group, so I need to show this directly, and I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those replacement rules are rather difficult to understand with all those $...$'s. Furthermore, as far as I am able to understand the rules as you wrote them, something seems off. For example, in place of rule (3) as written I might have expected instead something like this: replacing an edge path of the form $u a_{i-1} a_i a_{i+1} v$ with $uv$, where $u$, $v$ are sub edge paths, and where the sub edge path $a_{i-1} a_i a_{i+1}$ goes once around the boundary of a 2-simplex. I am even less able to understand rules (1) and (2) as written.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry, I could've been much clearer. The $a_i$ are the sequences of vertices the path follows, and here's a diagram illustrating rules (1) and (2) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUqfA.png) to make it clearer. I've updated the post with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you *can* work with the fundamental group, because certain statements about path homotopies can be translated into fundamental group statements, *even* for paths which are not closed. For example, given two paths $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 : I \to K$ with the same initial endpoints $p = \alpha_1(0)=\alpha_2(0)$ and the same terminal endpoints $q = \alpha_1(1)=\alpha_2(1)$, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_1$ are path homotopic if and only if the closed path $\alpha_1 * \bar\alpha_2$ represents the identity element of the fundamental group $\pi_1(K,p)$.

Thus, the statement you are trying to prove is *equivalent* to the statement that a closed edge path in $K$ based at a vertex $p$ represents the identity if and only if it is equivalent as an edge path to the trivial edge path at $p$.

What you need next is a theorem that is usually expressed in far greater generality, namely for a CW complex. This theorem gives an explicit presentation of the fundamental group $\pi_1(K,p)$.

To describe the presentation first choose a maximal tree $T$ in the 1-skeleton $K^{(1)}$. List the remaining edges of $K^{(1)}-T$ as $E_i$, and choose an orientation of each $E_i$.

The generating set of the presentation consists of one element $g_i$ for each $1$-cell $E_i$, where $g_i$ is the homotopy class of the following path: starting from $p$, in the maximal tree take the unique edge path from $p$ to the initial endpoint of $E_i$; then concatenate with $E_i$; and then concatenate with the unique edge path from the terminal endpoint of $E_i$ back through the maximal tree back to $p$.

The relation set of the presentation contains one relation for each $2$-cell. In your situation where a 2-cell is a simplex, go around the simplex and write its edges as $E_{i_1},E_{i_2},E_{i_3}$. The relator is obtained by writing $g_{i_1} g_{i_2} g_{i_3}$ except that if $E_{i_j}$ is actually contained in the maximal tree then you just skip $g_{i_j}$.

With that, you should be able to put the pieces together to prove the statement you want.

---

Let me add that the one textbook I know which does a good job of both the simplicial complex situation of your question and the general theory of fundamental group is Spanier's "Algebraic Topology".